# Jquery hover activating on page load instead of hover

Tags: jquery

I've written a small script that, when a div is hovered over, a tab at the bottom of the div (which is hidden via overflow in css) will pop up.

It works perfectly when I load the page directly — however, when I access the page from a link for the first time, the tab is already popped up, and covering the entire div. When I mouseover (or refresh the page), it immediately pops back down and begins working as normal.

Can anyone help with what I've done wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".linkbox").hover(
   function(){
     $(".linkbox_text", this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        marginTop:'-175px'
     },'400','swing');
   },

   function() {
     $(".linkbox_text", this).animate({
        marginTop:'-35px'
     },'400','swing');
   });
});
```

Comment: use display :none  on your popup tab div

Comment: The problem is the top of the popup div is meant to be visible when in a regular state, when hovered the entire thing pops up.

Answer (score 0):

try to reposition your div on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // reposition the div on document ready
    $(".linkbox .linkbox_text").css({marginTop:'-35px'});

   $(".linkbox").hover(
   function(){
     $(".linkbox_text", this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        marginTop:'-175px'
     },'400','swing');
   },

   function() {
     $(".linkbox_text", this).animate({
        marginTop:'-35px'
     },'400','swing');
   });
});
```

Comment: No luck i'm afraid. The problem resolves itself after the page is refreshed, I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out what's going wrong.